# Javascript JS optional

Tags: javascript, regex

So the following regular expression `re` works in JAVA but not in javascript. It looks like a very basic question. How can I make it so, that the `[A-Za-z]+` part would be optional in js?

```
var re = /\w+\s+[A-Za-z]+?/g;
var str = "John Smith";
$("#ret1").text(re.test(str)); // true
$("#ret12").text(re.test("sssa "));// false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match 0 or more characters (as your intent seems to be), you need to use `*` quantifier:

```
\w+\s+[A-Za-z]*
              ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT9sL9/1)

The `+?` quantifier requires to match at least 1 character and more, but as few as possible to return a valid match.

I see you confused `?` and `*?` quantifiers. When adding `?` after `+` or `*` the former turn into the so-called *lazy* quantifiers meaning they will match 0 (`*`) or 1 (`+`) characters and then any more characters but as few as possible. Here is an excerpt from [rexegg.com with the quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) supported by JavaScript engine:

> `A+`  - One or more As, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)
>
> `A+?`  One or more As, as few as needed to allow the overall pattern to match (lazy)
>
> `A*`   Zero or more As, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)
>
> `A*?`  Zero or more As, as few as needed to allow the overall pattern to match (lazy)
>
> `A?`   Zero or one A, one if possible (greedy), giving up the character if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)
>
> `A??`  Zero or one A, zero if that still allows the overall pattern to match (lazy)

Comment: k, that was a bad one from me. I was keen on knowing how can I use `?` to make it optional... thanks! :D

Comment: I have added the description of all quantifiers available in JS using the data from rexegg.com.

Comment: @MihkelL. `?` does indeed mean optional when used after a token or a group like so `colou?r` wich matches `color` or `colour`. However, when used after an another quantifier, it turns into a greediness switch. [see more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Comment: @stribizhev The first sentence in your answer isn't exactly true. The `*` means _zero or more_, not _optional_, which would be `\w+\s+[A-Za-z]?` a _zero or one_.

Comment: @Qwerty: If some pattern can match zero characters, I call it optional. `?` also makes matching the preceding pattern optional.